# defining axis breaks based on other column without saving dataframe before

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I am frequently creating plots like the one below with axis ticks/label indicating cumulative sums. This is all fine, but requires that I create the tibble before I can address the new breaks with `scale_y_continous(breaks=my_df$cumsum)`.

```r
library(tidyverse)


my_df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~group, ~value,
  "a",  10,
  "b",  20,
  "c",  60
  ) %>% 
  mutate(group=as_factor(group)) %>%
  arrange(desc(group)) %>% 
  mutate(value_cum=cumsum(value))
my_df
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   group value value_cum
#>   <fct> <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 c        60        60
#> 2 b        20        80
#> 3 a        10        90

my_df %>% 
  ggplot()+
  geom_bar(aes(fill=group,
               y=value,
               x=1),
           stat="identity",
           position=position_stack())+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=my_df$value_cum)+
  coord_flip()+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

To make things a bit smoother, I was wondering whether there is actually a way to address the newly created `value_cum` variable directly, 'on the fly', without being required to save the dataframe/tibble before. The failed attempt below hopefull makes clear what I am interested in. The issue is basically how can I adress values which are fed into the ggplot, but have not been saved before.

Many thanks.

```r
tibble::tribble(
  ~group, ~value,
  "a",  10,
  "b",  20,
  "c",  60) %>% 
  mutate(group=as_factor(group)) %>%
  arrange(desc(group)) %>% 
  mutate(value_cum=cumsum(value)) %>% 
  ggplot()+
  geom_bar(aes(fill=group,
               y=value,
               x=1),
           stat="identity",
           position=position_stack()) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=.$value_cum))+  #does not work
  coord_flip()+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: It works on my end if I change `.$value_cum` to `.data$value_cum`

Comment: @AHart Many thanks. Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. I simply get a blank axis (no ticks or labels). I am using ggplot2 package version ‘3.2.1.9000’.

Comment: Sorry for not catching that! I've added an answer below using braces to encapsulate the plot. I hope that works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should work if you put the entire plot in braces and specify the data in the initial call to `ggplot`:

```
tibble::tribble(
  ~group, ~value,
  "a",  10,
  "b",  20,
  "c",  60) %>%
  mutate(group = as_factor(group)) %>%
  arrange(desc(group)) %>% 
  mutate(value_cum = cumsum(value)) %>% 
  {
    ggplot(.)+
      geom_bar(aes(fill=group,
                   y=value,
                   x=1),
               stat="identity",
               position=position_stack()) +
      coord_flip()+
      scale_y_continuous(breaks=.$value_cum) +  #does not work
      theme(axis.text.y = element_blank())  
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function. There are a few ways to go about this ranging in complexity. Here are a few on the more simple end of the scale. Unfortunately, I don't think passing the source data frame back into the custom function is trivial.

**Data**

```
my_df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~group, ~value,
  "a",  10,
  "b",  20,
  "c",  60
)
```

**Wrap the whole plot into a function**

```
f_plot <- function(df) {

  my_breaks <- df %>% 
    mutate(group=as_factor(group)) %>%
    arrange(desc(group)) %>% 
    mutate(value_cum=cumsum(value)) %>%
    pull()

  ggplot(my_df) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill=group,
                 y=value,
                 x=1),
             stat="identity",
             position=position_stack()) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = my_breaks) +
    coord_flip() +
    theme(axis.text.y = element_blank())
}
```

```
f_plot(my_df)
```

**Wrap the breaks calculation into a function**

```
scale_breaks1 <- function(df) {

  my_breaks <- df %>% 
    mutate(group=as_factor(group)) %>%
    arrange(desc(group)) %>% 
    mutate(value_cum=cumsum(value)) %>%
    pull()

  scale_y_continuous(breaks = my_breaks)

}
```

```
ggplot(my_df) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=group,
               y=value,
               x=1),
           stat="identity",
           position=position_stack()) +
  scale_breaks1(my_df) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

**Push the graph object into a function**

```
scale_breaks2 <- function(p) {

  df <- p$data

  my_breaks <- df %>% 
    mutate(group=as_factor(group)) %>%
    arrange(desc(group)) %>% 
    mutate(value_cum=cumsum(value)) %>%
    pull()

  p + scale_y_continuous(breaks = my_breaks)

}
```

```
p <- ggplot(my_df) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=group,
               y=value,
               x=1),
           stat="identity",
           position=position_stack()) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank())

p %>% scale_breaks2()
```